# How to resolve function overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an overloaded pair of functions that take a single argument.  One takes a `uint64_t`.  The other takes an `int64_t`.  When I pass a `uint32_t` to the function it is correctly flagged as ambiguous.

How do I resolve this ambiguity without resorting to templates?  I can write a shallow wrapper that uses type traits to resolve it, but I would rather not.  I would prefer for signed types to resolve to the signed overload, and unsigned types to resolve to the unsigned overload.

Also, I would rather not have an overload for each integer type.

Comment: Make an overload that takes a `uint32_t` and forward it to the function you want called?

Comment: You don't need an overload for every integer type. Just the ones with conversion rank greater than or equal to that of `int`. That's 6 overloads. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @Brian How does that work when a short is passed to the function?

Comment: @Graznarak it gets promoted to `int` unambiguously.

Comment: [template version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64f9a075daf31b93).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options at your disposal:

1. Require the caller to explicitly cast to either `int64_t` or `uint64_t`.
2. Provide an overload for every integer type
3. Use templates, and either SFINAE or tag-dispatch on signed-ness.

(3) would be (in my opinion) the clearest, (2) would be the most verbose, and (1) would require the most work on your users.